# Assigning values in Pandas dataframe based on values from other field

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this

```
            1    2        3        4         5
date                    
2015-01-02  a   NaN     9.04    5604.81     Misc
2015-02-02  b   NaN     9.41    5200.24     Misc
2015-03-02  c   NaN     8.81    6070.10     Misc
2015-04-01  d   NaN     9.73    6934.83     Misc
```

I would like to change the value at 5 based on the values at 1. I tried:

```
data['5'][data.1=='a']='something'
```

But that would give me the following warning

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Job's done but I thought there should be a better way of doing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're performing [chain indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) this raises a warning in recent versions. For insertion, updating it is recommended to use the new `loc`, `iloc` and `ix` for indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should be using `ix`

```
df.ix[df['1']=='a', '5'] = 'Something'
```

Or `loc`

```
df.loc[df['1']=='a', '5'] = 'Something'
```

Although chained indexing works, it leads to problems sometimes

```
df['5'][df['1']=='a'] = 'Something'
```

---

You may want to read further on Pandas [indexing and assignment](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)